# Text Box Text From Local database on WP8.1 Visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Good Day!. I am trying for retrieving Local database values and showing into textBox.!
I have to put a very long text on a " textbox " , and I need a local database to read the text to be put into the text box .
How do I enter text inside the database ? how do we associate the text to textbox ?

I'm looking for a simple example , which only this , a textbox and a database.Ho found tutorials but are dispersive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must first look at the [31 days of Mango](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/10/31/31-days-of-mango), specially the day [#30](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/30/31-days-of-mango-day-30-local-database/)